# Know which plugin is calling JS in wp_head()?

Tags: plugins, headers

I'm trying to optimize my header and I was wondering which plugin would call jquery.
Is there a debugging tool to know which plugin is doing what in the header ?

Thanks !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Plugins and themes tend to use `wp_enqueue_script()` to queue up scripts for the `<head />` of your theme.

I would rarely advise this, but since you only need to do it temporarily, you could modify WordPress core and run a debug backtrace for every call to this function.

In `wp-includes/functions.wp-scripts.php`, drop the following code inside the end of the `wp_enqueue_script()` function (starts at line 96).

```
global $_script_callers_backtrace;
if ( !$_script_callers_backtrace )
    $_script_callers_backtrace = array();

$backtrace = debug_backtrace();
$_script_callers_backtrace[] = array( $handle, $backtrace[0]['file'] );
```

Now pop the following in your theme's `functions.php`;

```
function __save_script_callers()
{
    file_put_contents( WP_CONTENT_DIR . '/callers.' . date('d-m-Y-H-i-s')  . '.log', print_r( $GLOBALS['_script_callers_backtrace'], true ) ); 
}
add_action( 'shutdown', '__save_script_callers' );
```

Now whenever you load a page on your website, a log gets generated in your WordPress `wp-content` folder that'll contain a list of the script handlers and the files that triggered them.

**Remember!** Undo the changes once you've found out what you need!

Comment: Thanks ! I also found out about the wp_enqueue_style function, which allowed me to remove the calls to very small css files.

Answer (score 3):

There is a nifty little function called [debug_filters()](https://gist.github.com/796546) which lists the callbacks registered on a certain hook.

You would call from your theme, at the end of the header.php file for example:

```
<?php debug_filters('wp_head'); ?>
```

Comment: Nice! But surely that's no guarantee it'll show all plugins firing `wp_enqueue_script()?` Only ones hooked to `wp_head`?

Comment: Sure, but it's a starting point. You could also pass 'template_redirect', to catch more.